# Limit of Poisson random variables with parameters tending to infinity

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, weak-convergence, poisson-distribution

I have two independent Poisson distributed random variables: $\xi$ with parameter $\lambda$ and $\eta$ with parameter $\mu$. I need to show that $${{(\xi - \lambda) - (\eta - \mu)}\over{\sqrt{\xi + \eta}}} \rightarrow N(0,1)\:as\:\lambda,\mu\:\rightarrow\infty $$ where $N(0,1)$ is standard normal distribution. I've tried to do it using the fact that Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ can be approximated by Normal when $\lambda$ is large enough, but i am confused with calculatng the ratio of random variables.
Will be very glad for any hints.

Comment: It may be good to start with, in the denominator, $\sqrt{\lambda+\mu}$ instead of $\sqrt{\xi+\eta}$ (and then prove separately that the ratio $\frac{\xi+\eta}{\lambda+\mu}$ converges to one a.s.) (?).

Comment: I don't have sum of random variables in numerator, only their difference, so i can't understand how it can help. May be you have suggested to prove that ${{\xi - \eta}\over{\lambda + \mu}}$ converges to one?

Comment: No, I did mean the sum. (This is equivalent to proving that $\frac{\sqrt{\lambda+\mu}}{\sqrt{\xi+\eta}} \to 1$ a.s., so that you could try to prove this and that the other term I suggested converges to a standard normal in distribution).

Comment: All right, now I get it. I will try to do it and update the question later.